# Store git-flow branch naming configuration in the repository

Tags: git, git-flow

Currently, each user has to configure Git-flow first after having cloned the repository. How to store this branch naming configuration in a committable file (to be stored in the repository), so after having cloned the repository, it can be used with Git-flow out of the box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

git-flow stores its configuration using `git config` which writes to the `.git/config` file in each repository. This file is not versioned as it represents that individual user's preferences.

You could write a script that calls the appropriate `git config` commands and then version that (expecting each user to run the script once). Check your own `.git/config` file for what settings you would need to set.

Comment: This answer is correct but highlights an issue with git flow: branch naming and tag prefixes for releases should not be up to an individual's preference but should be specified project-wide.  Perhaps a .git-flow file would be a good feature.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking to ask a somewhat related question but reading your answer gave me the insight I needed to try to figure out the solution to my issue.